# KeyError thrown when parsing data scraped into columns

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, selenium

Sorry if this is a rookie question
I'm trying to scrape Zillow for houses listed in pre-foreclosures for my business and I am receiving a key error when separating the data into columns to convert into a CSV file

[this is the code I used that threw the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gm9nR.png)
[this is the error I received](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsKYG.png)

Comment: the first line in you loop is using df[col] before it's created so you get an error as there is no "beds" column in you df. By the way, in Colab, click on the "4 frames" arrows to see the full error, that will help to debug.

Comment: thank you for the tip! when i tried to seperate it out in the df it then gave me this: ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 4 elements, new values have 6 elements what can i do to make them match?

Comment: It seems to indicate that you have 4 columns and you are trying to add a row that has 6 elements. It would be easier if you share the code and a sample of the data (in text not in picture) so we can reproduce and help more